# jquery: how to use selector in cloned object?

Tags: jquery, clone

i clone a table using jquery and did not append it to the webpage. Now i like to use .show() on the cloned object to show hidden rows in the cloned object. At the end i send the cloned object to an excel export script. Therefore i did not append it to the webpage.

Plz see my code, on button click i do:

```
var cln = $('#test').clone();
cln('.entry').show(); // wont work
var wb = XLSX.utils.table_to_book(cln[0], {sheet:sheetname, raw: false, cellDates: true, dateNF: 'dd.mm.yyyy;@' });
```

This is my table and the jquery code loaded at start

```
<table id="test">
<tr><td>ROW 1</td></tr>
<tr class="entry"><td>ROW 2</td></tr>
</table>

$(function () {
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        $('.entry').hide();    
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use `cln.find('.entry').show();`  instead of `cln('.entry').show();`. And you can remove the inner `$(document).ready(function() {})` since it is not necessary:

```
$(function() {
  $('.entry').hide();

  // Rest of your code...
});
```